# Add custom classes for blocks in editor based on custom attributes

Tags: javascript, wp-admin, block-editor

I have been able to add additional classes to the `core/heading` block using `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps` filter, however, this only adds the class on the frontend, I would also like that custom class to be applied to the block element in the editor as followed.

[image]

I know i can use the `blocks.getBlockDefaultClassName` filter but dont know if I could do that based on custom attributes assigned to the block. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to assign a class to inner elements? Perhaps you don't need this? To style an element, this is definitely not necessary.

Comment: So that I can replicate the style that is shown on the frontend for those components.
e.g. the <h4> element would have a class with `text-large` when assigned a particular attribute. 

I want to be able to let the content managers to see the same style while they are editing the content using the editor. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `editor.BlockListBlock` filter. More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blocklistblock). This allows you to do something like the following:

```
const withCustomAttributeClass = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const { attributes } = props;
        const { yourCustomAttribute } = attributes;
        const class = yourCustomAttribute ? 'my_custom_class' : '';

        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className={ class } />;
    };
}, 'withCustomAttributeClass' );

addFilter(
    'editor.BlockListBlock',
    'your-plugin/custom-attribute-class',
    withCustomAttributeClass
);
```

In the above, I am just checking if the attribute exists and then am applying a class, but you could do all sorts of more complicated things here. Note that this filter will apply the class to every block with that custom attribute. However, `props` contains all of the block information, so you could exclude certain blocks as needed if you wanted.